# How to Get Value from GridView (row click) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

Hello i using Telerik GridView  i cach event (double click on row) and it works.
    Here code in javascript

```
 function RadGrid1_OnRowDblClick(sender, args) {
                console.log(sender);

            }


Now i need to get value from this Row (this row have ProductID,ProductLoad,Distance),i my case i need the ProductID of the row that i double clicked.

Sow how can i do this?
```

This is right ans
args.getDataKeyValue("ProductID")

But very important to add

```
 <MasterTableView Width="100%" ClientDataKeyNames="ProductID">
        </MasterTableView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `args.get_itemIndexHierarchical();` within the `RadGrid1_OnRowDblClick`gives you the row number that you double clicked. Is this what you were looking for.

Comment: No i need value from the row like ProductID,ProductLoad

Comment: You could do `args.getDataKeyValue("ProductID")` and so on.

Comment: [Example here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/keys/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: Find it i was missing ClientDataKeyNames="ProductId" in MasterTableView You need to add this my your self